# Enum with PropertyObject in Hibernate and JavaFX

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx

I've got a class with some fields, one of them is `SimpleObject` type which keeps appropriate value of enum type (look below). How am I able to save this field (bloodType) in database but as `ObjectProperty<BloodType>` not `enum`? I can't change the type of variable to enum because i will lose ability to observe it in `TableView`.

I've tried to annotated it with @Embadded but it seems it works only for classes.

After executing my code I recive an exception:

```
 Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Attribute [model.Patient.bloodType] was annotated as enumerated, but its java type is not an enum [java.lang.Object]
```

Class Patient:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Donors")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
class Patient
{

        (...)
        @Column(name="Blood_Type")
        private ObjectProperty<BloodType> bloodType = new SimpleObjectProperty<BloodType>();

        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        public Object getBloodTye() {
            return bloodType.get().toString();
        }
        public void setBloodTye(Object bloodType) {
            this.bloodType.set((BloodType) bloodType);
        }

}
```

And enum type:

```
public enum BloodType {
A_PLUS,
A_MINUS,
AB_PLUS,
AB_MINUS,
B_PLUS,
B_MINUS,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a return type that is a enum type. However your getter/setter is written as if the property was of type `Object`. Change this to `BloodType`.

Note that it's extremely bad practice anyways. This may just lead to `ClassCastException`s. You haven't even documented them and it's easy to prevent them by using `BloodType` as the type. Hibernate handles the conversion from the enum type to `String` anyways.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Donors")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
class Patient
{

    (...)
    private ObjectProperty<BloodType> bloodType = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="Blood_Type")
    public BloodType getBloodType() {
        return bloodType.get();
    }
    public void setBloodType(BloodType bloodType) {
        this.bloodType.set(bloodType);
    }

}
```